# how to play dgram audio message in nodejs

Tags: java, android, html, node.js

Excuse me if I do not speak good English
I record my voice on the phone and send live server (with dgram socket)
And the following code,  I transmit it to all users on a server
I wanted to see what a user can receive and broadcast sound in Html page

```
var http = require('http');
var dgram = require('dgram');
var clients = [];

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "audio/mpeg", 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'});
        clients.push(res);
        console.log('Client connected; streaming');
    }).listen(8080, function() {
        console.log('Listening at: 127.0.0.1 8080');
    }
);

var srv = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
srv.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
        if (clients.length > 0){
            for (client in clients){
                clients[client].write(msg);
            };
        } 
});

srv.on("listening", function () {
  var address = srv.address();
  console.log("server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

srv.bind(50005);
```

and i send recorded data to the server with following java code in android :

```
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];
                    DatagramPacket packet;
                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("my server ip");
                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                    recorder.startRecording();

                    while(status == true) {

                        minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);
                        socket.send(packet);
                    }
```

please help me ...

Comment: You will have to describe what the problem is, not what you are doing.